# File is returning empty ("") when choosing from Intent in Android

Tags: java, android, file

I am trying to upload a video. What I have done is, I have downloaded one sample video and trying to select the video using intent. What I am expecting is The file I select, I will get that and pass to network and upload. Since I dont have any experience doing this before, I am having tough time to deal with it.

```
private void getFile() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), REQUEST_CODE_PICKER);
}
```

When I select the video, I am receiving an **uri** *onActivityResult*

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        String uriPath = uri.getPath(); // uriPath = "/document/video:7876"
        File fileToUpload = new File(uriPath); // fileToUpload = ""
        String videoPath = getRealVideoPathFromURI(getContentResolver(),uri); // videoPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/testVideo.mp4"
        File videoFile = new File(videoPath); // videoFile = ""
        uploadFile(videoFile);
    }
}
```

I tried both paths(realPath and uriPath) to see if I get any File. If I debug I can see the both ***fileToUpload*** and ***videoFile*** is "". To add, all permissions Read & Write are given.

here is the code for getting real video path from the **uri**

```
String getRealVideoPathFromURI(ContentResolver contentResolver ,
                            Uri contentURI){
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null)
        return contentURI.getPath();
    else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA);
        try {
            return cursor.getString(idx);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to understand what I am doing wrong? All I need is to upload the selected video file. Is the way I am doing it is wrong? If so, then what is the proper way of doing that? As I don't ask questions without searching and failed to find out, kindly try to give me proper answer which can help me sort out this. It could be my approach is wrong, it could be some device issue etc . Thanks

Comment: 1) As `File videoFile = new File(videoPath);` videoFile is declared within the `if` block it will go out of scope immediately you return 2) A file can not be `""`

Comment: Can you explain a bit more ? I did not get you. @ScaryWombat

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to get Path.

Also you should pass the realpath in new File(getPath(this,data.getData()).

```
 /**
 * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
 * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
 * other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri The Uri to query.
 * @author paulburke
 */
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri The Uri to query.
 * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}


/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

Comment: So basically you mean, my path is inaccurate?
Did you try my code? or just giving your solution? It would be helpful for me if you could take my code, convert whatever way you want and then return. 
For instance, you replace my getPath code to your and try.
I tried, the result is same.

Comment: Whenever you pass a uri it should be like this /storage/emulated/0/Download/testVideo.mp4 not like /document/video:7876 which it is in your case . And i am using above mentioned solution for uploading videos to Amazon S3

Comment: Now I know, you did not read my post carefully. Let me give you the snippet again in case you missed it,

String videoPath = getRealVideoPathFromURI(getContentResolver(),uri); // videoPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/testVideo.mp4"
File videoFile = new File(videoPath); // videoFile = ""

This is the file I am trying to upload. but this one returns "".

the path you said(mentioned below), I added to make others understand what I did. 

String uriPath = uri.getPath(); // uriPath = "/document/video:7876"
File fileToUpload = new File(uriPath); // fileToUpload = ""